# R array permutation naming columns and rows

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

This is a follow up question to **[convert 4-dimensional array to 2-dimensional data set in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676143/convert-4-dimensional-array-to-2-dimensional-data-set-in-r?answertab=active#tab-top)** which was [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/216791/ben-bolker) by @Ben-Bolker.

I have a 3D array called 'y' with dimensions [37,29,2635] (i.e. firms, years, class). Using Ben's formula:

```
avm11<-matrix(aperm(y,c(1,3,2)),prod(dim(y)[c(1,3)]))
```

I managed to convert it to a 2D array with dimensions [37*2635,29]. However, the row names have become meaningless numbers and I'd need to generate row names during the permutation so that I'd get 97495 unique row names of the type firm_class.

I've been trying to do so via `paste0()` but I'm doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps, adding something like `dimnames = list(do.call(paste, expand.grid(dimnames(y)[c(1,3)])), dimnames(y)[[2]])` in your call to `matrix(aperm...)`? BTW, something like `as.data.frame(as.table(y))` could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @alexis_laz. This solution works perfectly and very quickly. I do not understand what is happining behind the scenes but the result is fantastic! thanks so much! Also good advice on the data.frame thing. Maybe that will make further computations easier indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `seq_len()` for this. E.g.

`rownames(avm11)<-paste(seq_len(length(avm11[,1])),"observation",sep=" ")`

To make the rownames dependable on the variable firm_class:

```
#Create data frame:
df<-data.frame(X=c(0,1,2,3,4,5),Y=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"))
n<-length(df[,1])

#Generate names containing class name and unique number:
namevector<-sapply(seq_len(n),function(i) names_vector[i]<-paste("Class", df[i,1], i,sep="."))

#Equate rownames to generated names:
rownames(df)<-namevector
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I however seem to get an error message: Error in seq_len(length(avm11[, 1]), "observation", sep = " ") : 
  3 arguments passed to 'seq_len' which requires 1 . Also I'm trying to get rownames for the new matrix (avm11) I generate, not for the one I use to generate the new matrix  (y), see update question.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the second `)` to close the seq_len commmand. Just substitute y for avm11 to do it for your new matrix. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks again @Pinemangoes. This indeed adds a rowname to the entire matrix but it does not solve my problem entirely as all rownames are now called observation while I need to be called firm_class (with 37 different firm names and 2635 different classes in the real database). Can seq_len incorporate that?

Comment: You want the rownames to be dependent on the value of a variable? Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi again, in my original question I specified that "I'd need to generate row names during the permutation so that I'd get 97495 unique row names of the type firm_class". Thus, every row in avm11 must have a name of the combination firm (1 out of 37) and class (1 out of 2635). I know this is possible via paste0 but because the permutated matrix avm11 is longer than the array y, I have to generate the names while doing the permutation...

Comment: Might be a good idea to generate the rownames vector before you do the conversion to 2D. Then you could just specify `rownames(avm11)<-namevector`.